# Nuxt/ Vue bug for calling server multiple times on a single route/ page?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, nuxt.js

Why does Nuxt call the server for so **many times** on a **single** route/ page?

Below is the example I tested from their [express-template](https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template):

```
import express from 'express'
import { Nuxt, Builder } from 'nuxt'

import api from './api'

const app = express()
const host = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.set('port', port)

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(res.headersSent) // <-- pay attention here
  next()
})

// Import API Routes
app.use('/api', api)

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
let config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')

// Init Nuxt.js
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

// Build only in dev mode
if (config.dev) {
  const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
  builder.build()
}

// Give nuxt middleware to express
app.use(nuxt.render)

// Listen the server
app.listen(port, host)
console.log('Server listening on ' + host + ':' + port) // eslint-disable-line no-console
```

This [route/page/index.vue](https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template/blob/master/template/pages/index.vue) will call the `api/users`:

```
import axios from '~/plugins/axios'

export default {
  async asyncData () {
    let { data } = await axios.get('/api/users')
    return { users: data }
  },
  head () {
    return {
      title: 'Users'
    }
  }
}
```

I added a `console.log` in [plugins/axios.js](https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template/blob/master/template/plugins/axios.js):

```
import * as axios from 'axios'

let options = {}
// The server-side needs a full url to works
if (process.server) {
  options.baseURL = `http://${process.env.HOST || 'localhost'}:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`
  console.log('express:' + options.baseURL)
}

export default axios.create(options)
```

When I run the app and access it on my browser at http://127.0.0.1:3000/:

In my terminal I get:

```
false
express:http://localhost:3000
false 
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

As you can see that it has called `api/users` **8 times** more **after** the **first** call.

Is it a **bug** in Nuxt?

If I removed `app.use(nuxt.render)` from [server/index.js](https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template/blob/master/template/server/index.js):

```
// Give nuxt middleware to express
// app.use(nuxt.render)
```

And I access it at http://127.0.0.1:3000/ or http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/users, I get:

```
false
```

Just **one** call which is correct.

So, what is going on with Nuxt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug. Express is executing your middleware. In this case, they are http requests for client assets like `app.js`, `logo.png` etc. Change your middleware code like below and check the console.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.url) // Change this line
   next()
})
```